# How to permanently set environmental variables

Tags: environment-variables

My variables are

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib
ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64
```

How to save these variables permanently ?

Comment: The other answers on this page are great. One small recommendation would be to add `/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib` in a new file under the `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` path. Then you don't need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH, see also [here](http://linux.101hacks.com/unix/ldconfig/).

Comment: Careful, there is more to this story than initially appears. [I invite you to check my answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13667284/how-do-i-keep-functions-variables-local-to-my-zshrc/42081254#42081254)

Answer (score 374, accepted):

You can add it to the file `.profile` or your login shell profile file (located in your home directory).

To change the environmental variable "permanently" you'll need to consider at least these situations:

1. Login/Non-login shell
2. Interactive/Non-interactive shell

#### bash

1. Bash as login shell will load `/etc/profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, `~/.profile` in the order
2. Bash as non-login interactive shell will load `~/.bashrc`
3. Bash as non-login non-interactive shell will load the configuration specified in environment variable `$BASH_ENV`

```
$EDITOR ~/.profile
#add lines at the bottom of the file:  
     export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib
     export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64
```

#### zsh

```
$EDITOR ~/.zprofile
#add lines at the bottom of the file:  
     export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib
     export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64
```

#### fish

```
set -Ux LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib
set -Ux ORACLE_HOME /usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64
```

#### ksh

```
$EDITOR ~/.profile
#add lines at the bottom of the file:  
     export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib
     export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64
```

#### bourne

```
$EDITOR ~/.profile
#add lines at the bottom of the file:  
     LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib     
     ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64
     export LD_LIBRARY_PATH ORACLE_HOME
```

#### csh or tcsh

```
$EDITOR ~/.login
#add lines at the bottom of the file:  
     setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib
     setenv ORACLE_HOME /usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64
```

If you want to make it permanent for all users, you can edit the corresponding files under `/etc/`, i.e. `/etc/profile` for Bourne-like shells, `/etc/csh.login` for (t)csh, and `/etc/zsh/zprofile` and `/etc/zsh/zshrc` for zsh.

Another option is to use `/etc/environment`, which on Linux systems is read by the PAM module `pam_env` and supports only simple assignments, not shell-style expansions. (See [Debian's guide](https://wiki.debian.org/EnvironmentVariables) on this.)

These files are likely to already contain some assignments, so follow the syntax you see already present in your file.

Make sure to restart the shell and relogin the user, to apply the changes.

If you need to add system wide environment variable, there's now `/etc/profile.d` folder that contains sh script to initialize variable.
You could place your sh script with all you exported variables here.
Be carefull though this should not be use as a standard way of adding variable to env on Debian.

Comment: This `.profile` in `/etc/` but I don't how to set the variables in this `.profile` please tell me

Comment: `.profile` is in your home  directory not `/etc/`

Comment: How to check this `.profile` in my home directory??

Comment: `[Admin@localhost etc]$ cat ~/.profile
cat: /home/Admin/.profile: No such file or directory
[Admin@localhost etc]$ 
`

Comment: what is your shell ?

Comment: I'm using bash shell

Comment: @user3021349 I don't meant to be rude but if you think one second you can also use a different editor you master. `:wq` is the command to write file and exit in vi don't forget to type `esc` before

Comment: sorry!! works fine .. Thank you foe efforts while answering my question and thank you for answering my question

Comment: Parts of this are grossly wrong: Bourne shell doesn’t allow `export x=y` but needs `x=y; export x`; the C shell uses `setenv`.

Comment: @mirabilos thanks, i proceed to an edit :-)

Comment: @Kiwy ok. Do note that `export x=y` works fine in the Korn shell, and that `.profile` is only read by login shells (some Korn shell variants use `.kshrc` or `.mkshrc` for interactive nōn-login shells). I’ll fix that for you.

Comment: You'll need to consider the environment variables in `crontab` scripts. None of these locations will be looked up when a `crontab` script is running.

Comment: @yegle as I change my answer to a wiki community please feel free to complete it I really don't know how to add variable for the `crontab`.

Comment: Much like `crontab` the env must be spelled out on OS X / macOS with `launchd` agents and daemons. It's easy to do, but important to remember.

Comment: I would also add that OS X / macOS may overwrite your /etc/profile during any system update. Your user account doesn't actually own that.

Comment: I wrote a small script that echo a $VARIABLE that is saved in ~/.profile, and it works, I mean, if I run ./foo,sh, it will print the variable value, why?

Comment: One more piece of information from https://wiki.debian.org/EnvironmentVariables: You can "put all global environment variables, i.e. ones affecting all users, into `/etc/environment` **but** this file is read by PAM, not by a shell. **You cannot use shell expansions** here. E.g. `MAIL=$HOME/Maildir/` will not work! There is no shell-agnostic and login-independent solution to the problem of how to configure the environment for all users, beyond the trivial cases that PAM can handle".

Comment: .... /etc/profile.d folder .....
Be carefull though this should not be use as a standard way of adding variable to env on Debian.

@Kiwy Why do you say like that? What should be taken care of in Debian distros if one were to put a script there?

Comment: I am trying to inject an environment variable into a podman container and would like it to work if either bash or just `sh` is available. I can get it working with bash by editing /etc/bashrc but I cannot figure out what file to modify for just `sh`. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 100):

To do if for all users/shells, depending on distro you could use `/etc/environment` or `/etc/profile`. Creating a new file in `/etc/profile.d` may be preferable if it exists, as it will be less likely to conflict with updates made by the packaging system.

In `/etc/environment`, variables are usually set with `name=value`, eg:

```
ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64
```

In `/etc/profile`, you must use `export` since this is a script, eg:

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64
```

Same goes for a file under `/etc/profile.d`, there also may be naming restrictions which must be met for the file to work. On Debian, the file must have the extension `.sh` (although does not need a bang line or executable permissions since it is sourced). check your distro documentation or look at the `/etc/profile` script to see how these files are loaded.

Note also though that setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` permanently is potentially [problematic](http://www.cc.dtu.dk/?page_id=304), including being a security risk. As an alternative, I would suggest finding some way to prepend the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the start of the command line for each program that needs it before running. Eg:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib myprog
```

One way to do this is to use a wrapper script to run the program. You could give this the same name as your program and put it in `/usr/local/bin` or anywhere that appears *before* the location of your program in `PATH`. Here is an example script (don't forget to `chmod +x` the script):

```
#!/bin/sh
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib /real/location/of/myprog "$@"
```

Comment: so, if I've added value pairs to my `environment` file, what causes those to load up? For example, after exiting vi editor (changes written successfully)  , I'm expecting to write `echo $MY_NEW_VARIABLE` and see it print out - EDIT: I see they're there if I launch a new command shell

Comment: Unsure if this is a personal issue or what, but I had to reboot my OS after setting this in `/etc/environment`, even if I restarted the bash terminal or typed `source /etc/environment`. So if you're having issues where the environment variable isn't perpetuating, try rebooting.

Comment: @bkwdesign @Blairg23, `/etc/environment` is not a script, so it cannot be sourced.  It's loaded at login time (and a handful of other system events) by PAM, so you can either logout/login or run a new login session in a terminal by `$ su <your username here>` to pick up the new values in that isolated session.  The values will disappear once you exit, so it's probably less error-prone to just fully logout/login.

Comment: ubuntu 20.04 here, `/etc/environment` didn't work but creating a `.sh` file in `/etc/profile.d/` did the trick, thanks :)

Comment: I tested the approach with just the `/etc/environment` file on CentOS 8 and I didn't need to restart I just needed to exit (log out) the terminal or create a new one (log in).

Comment: @Eduardo, careful with this. If your distro's login scripts are reading `/etc/environment`, that's great. But remember it only affects programs started under that login. If you want the environment change to affect other users, they will need to log in again too (and if you don't consider Kiwy's answer instead). Also, if you want the changes to affect system services, this may require a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify which flavour of UNIX you are using. On FreeBSD (and Net and Open BSD) you can use `/etc/login.conf`. Full details in the [man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=login.conf&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2012.2-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&arch=default&format=html) but you can add something like:

```
:setenv=ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64:
```

to the default class and it will be set for all users regardless of shell or lack thereof.

There are also PAM modules that can do something similar if you are using PAM. e.g [pam_env](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_env.html) which reads from `/etc/environment`.

Answer (score -1):

I find "How to save these variables permanently ?" ambiguous.

All answers seem to suppose that it means permanence in the meaning of "after a reboot".
I stumbled here looking for a way to persist ENVs for a bash session so that a production app could be run with ENVs set in the same process.

I'll leave this answer here for the like-minded.
The solution is to put them in a script like so:

set-envs.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
export ENV1="some value"
export ENV1="some value"
```

`chmod +x set-envs.sh` once to make it executable
and run it before the app with `source` (or it's shorthand `.` )

```
. ./set-envs.sh
./run-the-app.sh  # or such
```

Comment: There is no need to make a script executable if you source it, only if you execute it directly. It sounds like you actually want `ENV1=Foo ENV2=bar ./run-the-app`.