# Fixing my PATH variable

Tags: bash, path

When I type `echo $PATH`, I get the output:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

However, I modified my `PATH` variable using `gksudo gedit
/etc/environment`; the file now reads `PATH="/opt/texbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"`.

I am not sure why I am getting two different value of `PATH`. How can I fix it?

I am running Xfce on a Chromebook using Crouton.

Comment: What command did you use to modify your PATH variable?

Comment: @cremefraiche I used <code> gksudo gedit /etc/environment </code> and then  added <code> "/opt/texbin"</code> saved it rebooted but still the same problem.

Comment: That is not the way you should be changing your path variable. If you are trying to change the PATH variable for the current user only, modify the line in `~/.bashrc` that says `export PATH=$PATH:...`. All you need to do is add a colon to the end and include the path. Example: `export PATH=$PATH:...:/new/path`

Comment: @cremefraiche thanks let me try that. Btw would you explain why editing the PATh in /etc/environment doesnt work?

Comment: From what I understand it is best not to mess with that file directly, in order to minimize risk of breakage. I should mention that `~/.bashrc` is run every time an interactive shell is opened, while `~/.bash_profile` is run when a login shell is opened. Pick which file best suits your needs.

Comment: @DBS The obvious question is - what did you do after changing your path? Did you reboot? In any case, as cremefraiche says, changing system files in this fashion is not recommended. Change your `~/.bashrc` or similar. What do you need the `/opt/texbin` for?

Comment: @FaheemMitha After changing my path I rebooted. I tried changing the bashrc but it didn't work. I was trying to install Tex in my system follwoing the second answer here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu/95373#95373

Comment: The point is my terminal cannot access latex unless I add it to the PATH this is where the problem is.

Comment: @DBS what is your distribution? Why not use binary packages for your distribution? I'm a bit puzzled by that particular instruction. `/etc/profile` is where Debian/Ubuntu sets PATH.

Comment: If you look at the comments, a couple of people say that `/etc/environment` does not work, and I don't see why it should. See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu/95373#comment437238_95373 However, I recommend you just use `~/.bashrc`. I personally use the TeX Live binary packages though.

Comment: @FaheemMitha thank you for your answers. here is what I have <code>
Description: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS. I tried modifying my ~./bashrc file but it is not working. Does it have something to do with running linux over chrome using crouton?

Comment: When you say "but it is not working" what do you mean, exactly? What did you do after you modified the `~/.bashrc`?

Comment: Well I rebooted again started shell and `(ctrl+ alt+ t)` and typed `$PATH` the changes weren't there. when I typed `which latex` the shell prompt didnt respond.

Comment: Related:  [How can I cleanly add to $PATH?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/124444/80216)

Answer (score 3):

Edit

- `/etc/profile` to affect all users.
- `~/.bash_profile` to affect single users bash shell (so not this one, as it is for bash specific stuff).
- `~/.profile` to affect single user, all shells.

Note: If you have both `.profile` and `.bash_profile` and you want both to be read by bash, then you will have to add `. .profile` to your `.bash_profile`, as `.profile` is not read by default, if `.bash_profile exists`

## on `sudo`

- don't run your editor as root, so don't do `gksudo gedit «filename»`
- Avoid running X11 apps as root, so don't do `gksudo gedit «filename»`
- instead do `EDITOR=gedit sudoedit «filename»`. It will run the editor as you on a temporary file, it will copy the fill as root when you finish.

Answer (score 1):

The correct place to set your `PATH` is in `~/.bash_profile`:

```
PATH="$PATH:/some/extra/paths:/may/go/here"
```

The `PATH` variable should already be exported, so you shouldn't need to `export` it again (exporting it again has no further effect).

The default path for `bash` is hardcoded into the `bash` executable, and then further (possibly) modified in `/etc/profile` and (on some systems) `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

My guess is that the path set in `/etc/environment` is primarily used by non-shells, such as `cron` etc.

See also:

- [How to permanently set environmental variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117467)

Comment: The last path, _/etc/bash.bashrc_ is actually set in the macro `SYS_BASHRC` and can be changed at compile time. For example, [Artix Linux](https://gitea.artixlinux.org/packages/bash/src/commit/af358952fe09a713fc149c90c4b2bb97499127d6/PKGBUILD#L52) changes it to _/etc/bash/bashrc_.

Answer (score 0):

> update note: I wrote this for zsh but it works for bash as well.

Here is a trick I use to keep my path clean.
(Note: I load in zsh configs as separate files. This file needs to load first so an easy way to force that while maintaining standardized naming conventions is to use prefixes. Prefixing with `0_pathfix.zsh` will cause this to run before the other Zsh config files.)

```bash
# add to path if $1 is not already in path
pathAppend() {

  if ! echo $PATH | egrep -q "(^|:)$1($|:)" ; then
    PATH=$PATH:$1
  fi
}

# filters the path checking against itself for duplicates returns clean path then exports the clean path. 

PATH=$(echo "$PATH" | awk -v RS=':' -v ORS=":" '!a[$1]++{if (NR > 1) printf ORS; printf $a[$1]}'); export PATH;

# This ensures that even if you manually added to the path the next time zsh source is reloaded the path will clean itself.
```

Answer (score 0):

`/etc/environment` is the system wide fallback. The per-user config in `~/.bash_profile` probably overrides it. Regardless, don't mess with `/etc/environment` for configuring bash, instead put whatever `PATH` you want in `~/.bash_profile`. Even if `/etc/environment` is wrong it will be overridden by what you put in `~/.bash_profile`.

You should probably also restore `/etc/environment` to what it was before to avoid minor breakage with programs that depend on it. That file comes with the package, so you can use your package manager to reset it to its original form.