# Environment variable not getting retained for JRE_HOME with sudoers

Tags: bash, debian, sudo, java, lxde

OS: Linux (Debian 8)
Environment details:

1. We use LXDE and `uxterm`.
2. Virtual console form till ctrl +Alt + F6 is disabled.
3. Total users available **user1, user2, user3**

the default system is set with auto login with **user1** and we trigger user terminal via script (`uxterm`).

On user pressing special combination in LXDE it invoked a Uxterminal in screen with User2 as login. on login success, user2 console can be used.

We have 3rd user, where his role is very limited and needed for our current scenario of our operation.

To create a BASH profile for the user, we have added info in `sudoers` with `NOPASSWD` option.

**etc/sudoers**

```
User_Alias PRIVILEGEDUSER = user1,user2
Runas_Alias TARGETUSER = user2,user3
PRIVILEGEDUSER ALL=(TARGETUSER) NOPASSWD: /bin/bash
```

also we have added `env_keep` in `Defaults`

```
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        env_keep += "JRE_HOME"
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```

With this option when we try switching user, `JRE_HOME` is not getting set. Also added **JRE_HOME** in `etc/.profile` manually for all available users in system for testing purposed, even that did not help

```
JRE_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre
export JRE_HOME
```

Need some guidance in setting `JRE_HOME` during `sudo -u` switching.

Answer (score 0):

To set envrionment variables globally there are several approaches and as discussed under [How to set environment variable for everyone under my Linux system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641477/how-to-set-environment-variable-for-everyone-under-my-linux-system) or [How to permanently set environmental variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117467/how-to-permanently-set-environmental-variables).

For me placing a `.sh` file under `etc/profile.d` worked well.

Answer (score 0):

You can set specific environment variables in your /etc/sudoers file for a given user with:

```
Defaults:myuser-spec env_file=/etc/sudovars_for_myuser
```

For your example, you may have /etc/sudovars_for_myuser containing:

```
JRE_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre
```