# Start bash then autostart fish with terminator

Tags: bash, fish, gnome-terminator

I've been using terminator, and recently started using fish. When terminator starts (bash) I can use, for example, `node` just fine. If I then start fish I can still run `node` just fine.

I set terminator to "Run a custom command instead of my shell", in this case `fish`, but then I can no longer just run `node`. Terminal says it is not installed. I kinda can see what the problem is... If I run `fish` from `bash` everything just works... It makes sense, I am guessing...

How can I start `fish` automatically but have the bash stuff working already?

(It's clear I'm not sure what I'm talking about and that is perhaps why I could not find a solution via google...)

Comment: I'm not a node expert but I suppose node installation put some variables or is sourcing some settings in your bash files. So after loading bash you have your environment correctly set. Look into `~/.bashrc` and/or `~/.bash_profile` for some node configuration. If I am right, you will need to put such settings in fish configs (I don't know them).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your description of the symptoms, you've evidently installed `node` in a location which is not on your system's default command search path. There's nothing wrong with that, you just need to add that location to the `PATH` environment variable. That's what you did wrong: you did that in the wrong file.

Unfortunately, a lot of tutorials tell you to set `PATH` in `.bashrc`. This is wrong, as you've noticed: if you do that then the setting is only available if you start programs via an interactive instance of bash. Generally speaking, don't set environment variables in `.bashrc`. Instead, set environment variables in a file that is loaded as part of your session startup when you log in, such as `~/.profile`. See [Is there a ".bashrc" equivalent file read by all shells?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/is-there-a-bashrc-equivalent-file-read-by-all-shells/3085#3085) and [How to permanently set environmental variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117467/how-to-permanently-set-environmental-variables)

So the solution is to remove the `PATH` changes that you've added to `~/.bashrc` (either manually or by running some installation script) and put those lines in `~/.profile` instead.

To make the changes take effect in your current session, you need to change the environment in your window manager. This will affect any future terminal started from the window manager (there's no way to affect existing terminals). How to do that depends on the window manager.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are starting bash then starting fish. If fish is the shell you want to use then why not have it set as your default shell 
"chsh -s /usr/local/bin/fish" then on the rare occasions you want/need to run a bash command you simply type "bash" which drops you into a bash shell then once you finish you type "exit" to go back to fish.

More on this can be found at "https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell#switching-to-fish"