# How I can configure w3m to use squid proxy (or any proxy) by default when invoked by a specific user?

Tags: proxy, squid, w3m

Can I configure `w3m` to use `Squid` by default when invoked by a specific user in a bash login shell?

I've looked inside the `w3m` configuration file, but I don't see any setting were I can set `squid` as the default proxy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't tell a browser to “use Squid” as a proxy, you tell it to use whatever proxy is running on a certain host and port.

Many web browsers, including w3m, can take proxy settings from the environment. Set the variable `http_proxy`, e.g.

```
export http_proxy=http://localhost:3128/
```

Put this line in that account's `~/.profile`, or put the line `http_proxy=http://localhost:3128/` in `~/.pam_environment`.

If you want to proxy HTTPS as well, put a similar line with `https_proxy`.

Alternatively, you can configure the proxy in w3m's configuration file, with a line in `~/.w3m/config`

```
http_proxy http://localhost:3128/
```

This option can be set interactively in the options screen (press `o` then type `/proxy`<kbd>Enter</kbd> and type the proxy URL in the box for “URL of HTTP proxy host”).

You may want to set `no_proxy` as well to exclude some domains, e.g. set to `localhost,127.0.0.1`.

Comment: The option that you are suggesting to set interactively is for your user but it wouldn't work if as root I want to make a user to only use a specific proxy.

Comment: @VaTo You'd have to run w3m as that user in order to modify that user's configuration file, e.g. `su someuser -c w3m`

Comment: thank you, I also changed the title of the question so it just doesn't apply for squid proxies but for any proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer if someone needs it:

I just had to set the proxy to the `HTTP_PROXY` variable:

e.g. `export HTTP_PROXY="http://proxyURL:portnumber"`

and in my case that I had to do it for a specific user, I only had to open the `~/.bashrc` file for that user, and add the same line to it.

Comment: [Not `.bashrc`, that's for shell settings. Set environment variables in `.profile`.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117467/how-to-permanently-set-environmental-variables)