# Update $PATH variable that survives updates?

Tags: configuration, path, sles

We can put a 3rd party apps new global `PATH` in `/etc/profile`, appending to the original `$PATH`, ok.

But.. I can see that the `/etc/profile` file is provided by a package: aaa_base. What would happen if someone upgrade the aaa_base?

**The Q:** How can we ensure that the `$PATH` stays somewhere, where an upgrade wouldn't modify it?

Comment: Stays somewhere globally or locally?

Comment: globally on a server, for all users.

Comment: I haven't used SUSE for a while; does it have an /etc/profile.d/ directory?

Comment: yes, with many .sh files

Comment: See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/117473/117549

Comment: Also: https://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/etc.html mentions /etc/profile.d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have an existing `/etc/profile.d` directory (and presumably the corresponding `/etc/profile` or `/etc/${SHELL}rc` files that *source* files in that directory), I'd recommend placing an `/etc/profile.d/3rd-party-app.sh` and/or `/etc/profile.d/3rd-party-app.csh` file with the required code. If you are the packager of the 3rd-party app, you could include those files in the packaging so that they are installed, updated, and removed by the package manager. Otherwise, as a user of the software, placing those files there will make them unmanaged, and so unaffected by OS package updates.

UPDATE from OP:

https://www.suse.com/documentation/sles11/book_sle_admin/data/sec_adm_whatistheshell.html

/etc/profile
Do not modify this file, otherwise your modifications can be destroyed during your next update!

/etc/profile.local
Use this file if you extend /etc/profile

/etc/profile.d/
Contains system-wide configuration files for specific programs

Comment: https://www.suse.com/documentation/sles11/book_sle_admin/data/sec_adm_whatistheshell.html