# Debian Linux - Setting an environment variable for all users

Tags: debian, environment-variables

I added the following in `/etc/profile` so that all my users can see the path

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk11
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

But after restarting my laptop, I cannot see the changes using `echo $JAVA_PATH`. I thought there is an order for how the scripts are loaded. and Also, If I was to add this changes into a separate `sh` file in `/etc/profile.d`, it's supposed to do the same. So why is it that it's failing to see the path changes.

Comment: `JAVA_PATH` or `JAVA_HOME`? You assign one but mention the other in the `echo`.

Comment: @ilkkachu       thanks for correcting the typo

Comment: Just asking to verify that you didn't accidentally set the wrong variable. You could [edit] your question to clarify it, just so that no-one else makes the wrong interpretation.

Comment: See https://wiki.debian.org/EnvironmentVariables for the official stance.

Comment: All users might enjoy of variables, settings, aliases and other stuff which is places in `/etc/profile`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are testing in a non-interactive shell. For interactive shells, both /etc/profile and /etc/bash.bashrc are sourced, but for non-interactive shells, [only /etc/bash.bashrc is sourced](https://bencane.com/2013/09/16/understanding-a-little-more-about-etcprofile-and-etcbashrc/). You might try putting your variables in that file.

/etc/profile, ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, ~/.profile and related files on other shells are discussed at length in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/117470/176171).

Comment: I think it's the latter. Thanks for explaining the interactive shell concept. Appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

First lines in `/etc/bash.bashrc` state this:

```
System-wide .bashrc file for interactive bash(1) shells.

To enable the settings / commands in this file for login shells as well,
this file has to be sourced in /etc/profile.
```

So, system wide additional environment variables, to use in any user terminal, should be located in it. Even root environment will use these.