# Linux Redhat 7 : How to set a shell option globally / system-wide?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, rhel, shopt

I'm having some troubled time trying to figure out how to turn on the `xpg_echo` option of the bash for every shell that will get run on my Linux RedHat system (7.4).

I know I can have what I need (the purpose is to expands backslash-escape at anytime as all the shells are ported from an HP-UX server) by using `shopt -s xpg_echo`, it's working fine for most cases.

Now my problem is where to turn on this option "system-wide" or "globally" so that every shell that I will run uses it.

I tried putting `shopt -s xpg_echo` into one custom shell in `/etc/profile.d/myshell.sh`.

It's working fine for:

- Interactive shell sessions (get's sourced from `/etc/bashrc`)
- Login shell sessions (get's sourced from `/etc/profile`)
- shell programs without a bash shebang (that is no `#!/bin/bash` on 1st row)

but I can't get it to work in following cases, as it seems the `/etc/profile.d/` scripts don't get sourced and the `xpg_echo` option is not inherited from the calling shell:

- when running a shell script (with for example `echo "a\tb"`) as a `bash` argument, e.g. `bash /tmp/mytest.sh`
- when running a shell script that has the bash shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) on 1st row

I'd like to know if there is any way to turn on the shell option `xpg_echo` for every conditions where I need to run a shell.

NB: I'm using GNU bash, version 4.2.46

Comment: Welcome to UNIX&Linux at Stack Exchange. Thanks for posting your first question. It looks like this question has already been asked and answered [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117467/how-to-permanently-set-environmental-variables). Please review and if it does not apply, consider updating your question with additional details that require consideration.

Comment: @0xSheepdog The proposed dupe seems to be about environment variables, not `bash` shell options.  AFAIK, `bash` shell options are not inherited by child processes in the same manner as environment variables.

Comment: and it looks like u might just need `export xpg_echo`

Comment: @Kusalananda acknowledged, I wasn't sure thus my comment indicating how OP should proceed if they disagree. I'm still not clear on the point but it looks like others have weighed in. I'm not opposed to it reopening if OP can clarify.

Comment: @ron `xpg_echo` is a shell option in `bash`, not an environment variable. Exporting `xpg_echo` does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for pointing me to another [related topic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117467/how-to-permanently-set-environmental-variables).

To me the key was using the BASH_ENV variable.

As noted in the bash reference manual, there are [several way to open a shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html), the one causing me trouble was when it was invoked "non-interactively".

To workaround the fact that non-interactive shell don't run any `/etc/profile` nor `/etc/bashrc`, I created a dedicated shell script in `/etc/profile.d/`, e.g. "custom_shopts.sh" with only the shopt options that I'd like to have for every session and in this same script I will export variable `BASH_ENV=/etc/profile.d/custom_shopts.sh`

Therefore, in any shell that I run (login shell, interactive shell or non-interactive shell, but with the exception of `bash --posix`), the `/etc/profile.d/custom_shopt.sh` shell script will get run and position the shopt options I'm expecting.

Comment: I'd like to add that shell scripts ran from crontab are another special case. No environment is set for them, including the shell script refered by the BASH_ENV variable is also not run.