# Symbolic link to binary, can't find configuration file

Tags: symlink, john-the-ripper

I just installed the jumbo john package. 
it's in `~/tools/john` 
the binary is `~/tools/john/run/john`
and the config is `~/tools/john/run/john.conf`

I created a symbolic link with

```
sudo ln -s /home/me/tools/john/run/john /usr/local/bin/john
```

Now I get:

```
fopen: john.conf: No such file or directory
```

Am I doing this wrong? I'm in ubuntu 18.04.1
Thanks!

Comment: The sym link you created will only link to the binary john. Make another link to john.conf
`sudo ln -s /home/me/tools/john/run/john.conf /usr/local/bin/john.conf`

Comment: @MarkStewart It is likely that more files than just the configuration file will be picked up from the same directory, so creating a link for the configuration file will probably work for picking _it_ up, but will likely just cause other files to not be found later.

Comment: you said above that john is a binary ?  "binary is ~/tools/john/run/john"  
to link to the directory  sudo ln -s /home/me/tools/john/ /usr/local/bin/john

Answer (score 0):

According to the [`CONFIG` document in the `doc` subdirectory of the source distribution](https://github.com/magnumripper/JohnTheRipper/blob/bleeding-jumbo/doc/CONFIG), the `john.conf` file is looked for in "John's home directory".  A bit further on, a reference is made to a variable `$JOHN`, which I presume is an environment variable that will be use if it is set.

This is also mentioned slightly hidden (not properly marked up, in a parenthesis) half way down in [the `README.md` file](https://github.com/magnumripper/JohnTheRipper/blob/bleeding-jumbo/README.md):

> (in the documentation and in the configuration file for John, "$JOHN" refers to John's "home directory"; which directory it really is depends on how you installed John)

Therefore, it is fair to assume that the program is looking for the configuration file in the directory where the executable is located, or in `$JOHN`.  You may want to set this variable to where the files for the program are located, e.g.

```
export JOHN="$HOME/tools/john/run"
```

This could be done for an individual user, or system-wide.  See e.g. [How to permanently set environmental variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117467/how-to-permanently-set-environmental-variables)